# MSE of the train set is higher than MSE of test set?

Tags: machine-learning, mse

Suppose we have a linear regression model and we have a train set and a test set (randomly divided)

Is it possible that the MSE of the train test is higher than the MSE of the test test? In which cases?

I thought about one good reason for that - Outliers which can affect significantly the MSE.

Are there other good examples? Could the size of the set play a role too?  Maybe if there's no linear connection at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine a test set consinting of observation that perfectly match equation you got from train set. In such situation test-set-MSE is 0.

When does it happen? When you're lucky and future data fit your model better than data on which it was derived.

Or when you model is weak (high MSE), so it's easy to get better data for it by chance.

Or when your test set is small. It's again quite easy to have great-matching observations by chance.